# Add jQuery to a form to show/hide a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hide, show

I am trying to add some jQuery to a Wordpress site so that when a user selects a certain option (Software) in the top dropdown menu, another appears under it.

I am using the following code -

```
<p id="parent-menu">
    <select name='cat' id='cat' class='dropdown'  tabindex="40">
        <option value='-1'>Select a Category</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="13">Software problem</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="14">Hardware problem</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="15">Suggestion</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="16">General query</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p id="toggle-menu">
    <select name='cat' id='cat' class='dropdown'  tabindex="50">
        <option value='-1'>Select a Program</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="6">BigHand</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="7">IRIS</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="8">MS Outlook</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="9">MS Word</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="10">MS Excel</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="11">Oyez</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="12">Internet Explorer</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Id be greatful if someone could help me to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure on how wordpress handles JQuery but if I was writing this in PHP it would be something like. I would change taxonomy to id or value. And the query would go inside my button click. You would need to change your id for each click instance.

```
$(".class#id").toggle();
$(".dropdown#software").toggle();
```

ok. So on your new info. Since there is a specific id I can use. You will need to include something to check your code page for when the option 13 is selected. When that option is selected you would need something like this.

```
$("#toggle-menu").toggle();
```

or

```
$("#toggle-menu").show();
```

Now the idea here is that if you have this action or event based on selection of option using toggle() will show or hide toggle-menu depending on the selection, ie i selected it once it will appear, i deselect or select it again menu disappears. Using show() will make the toggle-menu appear but not hide it if deselected, in which case you would want to use a hide() in all other event selections to hide the toggle-menu

Comment: Please forgive the example above, I see now that I didn't include it as code properly. Hopefully this is a better description, and the code in the original post has been corrected. It's the code produced by WP and I would like for <p id="toggle-menu"> to be hidden unless the option with <value="13" is selected in <p id="parent-menu">. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery UI you might find Eric Hynds plugin useful: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: That is indeed very nice and has been saved for future use, although not appropriate in this instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming toggle menu doesnt care what was selected in the first menu, what you want is this

```
$('#parent-menu').change(function(event)
{
  $('#toggle-menu').show();
});

$('#toggle-menu').change(function(event)
{
  var selections = $('#parent-menu').val() + ' ' + $('#toggle-menu').val();
  alert(selections);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does matter what is selected in the first menu (value="13" is what I am looking for), so unfortunatly that's not quite what I am looking for. Thanks for the suggestion though.